# Incluir registros que no son join o inner join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, prestashop1.7

Estoy trabajando con una consulta en la base de datos de prestashop y la verdad no soy un experto con consultas sql, de momento me funciona bien pero necesito incluir tambien los que no son inner join. Para ser mas especifico quiero obtener productos que tienen combinaciones y es aqui donde entra el join, pero ademas necesito extraer tambien los productos que no tienen combinaciones, en esta parte es donde tengo mi duda, en incluir tambien los productos de la tabla `ps_product`

```
SELECT 
prod.id_product, prodla.name, prodat.reference, 
SUBSTRING(prod.price, 1, LENGTH(prod.price)-7) as precio, 
SUBSTRING(prodat.price, 1, LENGTH(prodat.price)-7) as precio_combinado, 
(prod.price + prodat.price) as diferencia, 
CEILING(((prod.price + prodat.price)*1.19)) as precio_con_iva 
FROM ps_product as prod 
JOIN ps_product_attribute as prodat 
JOIN ps_product_lang as prodla
WHERE prod.id_product = prodat.id_product AND prod.id_product = prodla.id_product
ORDER BY prod.id_product ASC
```

por ejemplo tengo 10 productos, de estos 5 tienen combinaciones, lo cual como total me darian 15 resultados en mi consulta, basandome en que tengo tambien 1 combinacion por cada producto combinado

Estaba pensado en un select que traiga todo de ps_product y un select dentro del select principal que traiga las combinaciones, no se si es posible hacerlo de esta forma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno ya lo he resuelto entre investigar y hacer algunas pruebas, utilice LEFT JOIN y RIGHT JOIN al estar trabajando con 3 tablas en total

```
SELECT prod.id_product, prodla.name, prod.reference, prodat.reference as referencia_combinaciones, 
SUBSTRING(prod.price, 1, LENGTH(prod.price)-7) as precio, 
SUBSTRING(prodat.price, 1, LENGTH(prodat.price)-7) as precio_combinado, 
(prod.price + prodat.price) as diferencia, 
CEILING(((prod.price + prodat.price)*1.19)) as precio_con_iva 
FROM ps_product as prod 
LEFT JOIN ps_product_attribute as prodat 
ON (prod.id_product = prodat.id_product)
RIGHT JOIN ps_product_lang as prodla
ON (prod.id_product = prodla.id_product)
ORDER BY prod.id_product ASC
```